# Is there any way to account for higher DPI scaling in case of Windows internal utilities

Tags: windows, resolution, scaling, high-dpi

Because of high resolution of my displays I have to turn to using higher DPI scaling (125% and 150%). Windows 10 is smart enough to take it into account when rendering most of the program windows, so GUI elements look sharp. Should it fail in certain cases, I can manually set the desired scaling on the «Compatibility» tab of program's shortcut properties. So far so good.

But it does not work for internal utilities like, say, «Local group policy editor» (gpedit.msc) or «Disk management» (diskmgmt.msc). Their GUIs are still blurred. There are no «Compatibility» tabs in their properties (probably, because they are some special type of executable).

Somewhat weird, is it? The OS is able to render third-party programs nicely, but fails to do so for its own utilities. Do I miss any thing? Can it be remedied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is here: Reg-File + Manifest.
Works also on Windows Server 2022 without reboot

https://serverfault.com/questions/570785/how-can-i-make-microsoft-management-console-high-dpi-aware-in-windows-8-1/1125964#1125964

Comment: Please see [how to write good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help): _"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. "_ Checking the Asking and Answering -sections, taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and reviewing some existing questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) is a good way to get a handle on how these sites work. Just hanging around and following some questions is also helpful.

Comment: Yes, it surely is! It really is the final and ultimate solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> But it does not work for internal utilities like, say, «Local group policy editor» (gpedit.msc) or «Disk management» (diskmgmt.msc). Their GUIs are still blurred. There are no «Compatibility» tabs in their properties (probably, because they are some special type of executable).

They're not really executables – they are *documents* for the Microsoft Management Console (which is `mmc.exe`). Only after the document is opened, it instructs MMC to load the "snap-in" code from some-or-other .dll file.

You could create a custom shortcut which explicitly refers to `mmc.exe` as the executable, passing a console document's file name as a command-line parameter – this should allow the "Compatibility" tab to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Interesting information. I tested the solution by creating a shortcut with target «C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe C:\Windows\System32\diskmgmt.msc» (without quotes). It does launch the «Disk management» utility, as you said, but for some reason the «Compatibility» tab is not on the shortcut properties form. I trust my account may lack some permissions (that being said, this is home computer, so the account belongs to the group «Administrators» and I am the only user).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Text Size. I use 125 % scaling and 110 % text size.

Then, in Start, Settings, right side and below the scale entry, click on Advanced Scaling Settings and enable (turn on) Fix scaling for Apps.

I started up gpedit and it is very clear.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion has worked... to some extent. I use 125% scaling as well and the option «Fix scaling for Apps» has been enabled since the moment I installed the OS. Setting text size to 110% does make windows like gpedit look better (clearer). But still not as good as third-party programs do. Of course, I played with this parameter, tried other values. That puzzled me, after all it was just arithmetic, so there should be some proper display scaling/text size ratio. Apparently, it is not that simple. Not a complete victory, but, like I said, it does look somewhat clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing to try (given this improvement) is to use Calibrate Color, and at the end of that there is a Clear Type adjustment. That may help further.

Comment: No, that did not improve any thing, sorry (I went through it and found that the best looking variants have already been selected on all five Clear type settings screens).

Nonetheless, thank you again. At least, now all this stuff does not look painful for eyes. It is a pity that this forum does offer some thing like «accepting answer as partial solution» :-).